# Is there any way to read session data(such as compute time, memory usage) from event file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm making the script that can extract data from tensorflow event file.

Basically, there are many ways to get summary data from event file.

But, it seems that there's nothing on how we can extract session data(such as each layer's compute time, and memory usage), which means runtime statistics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to his [section](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz#runtime_statistics) of the official documentation.

To summarize, you just need to add these 2 arguments:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
```

to your `sess.run` call to record runtime statistics, and add the `run_metadata` object to your writer:  `train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)`.

You will have access to the runtime statistics in TensorBoard in the graph tab.

```
[...]
else:  # Record train set summaries, and train
  if i % 100 == 99:  # Record execution stats
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                          feed_dict=feed_dict(True),
                          options=run_options,
                          run_metadata=run_metadata)
    train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    print('Adding run metadata for', i)
```

Comment: I know how to do this. But what I want to do is that after making an event file that has runtime statistics, i want to extract the runtime statistics from it shown in tensorboard, not summary of eventfile